# package install changepage

Tags: packages, installing

I am trying to install the package changepage. However I have the following displayed:

[image]

But the option 'install' leads to nothing... as no output pdf is produced (error: `changepage.sty not found`)

Then I tried to follow the instructions on the readme file. Now I face the problem that shows `filecontents.sty not found`. And somewhere I also came across something to do with a "remote repository". Please help

Comment: I assume you're running on MiKTeX. Don't install packages on-the-fly. Rather use the MiKTeX Package Manager (MPM) and update your distribution that way. See [How do I update my TeX distribution?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/5764)

Comment: @Werner:Thanks, when I use the package manager I get the following error message
Message: The remote package repository is not registered. You have to choose another repository.
Data: ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/systems/win32/miktex/tm/packages/
Source: Libraries\MiKTeX\PackageManager\PackageManager.cpp
Line: 2399
MiKTeX: 2.9
OS: Microsoft Windows XP Professional Service Pack 3 (build 2600)
SystemAdmin: yes
PowerUser: no
Root0: C:\Documents and Settings\n09040\Application Data\MiKTeX\2.9